# Retain Scroll position of Recycler view when App is closed and opened

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am looking to implement saving the scroll position of my recycler view similar to how Twitter does it. So when a user scrolls down x no of items, closes the app, and then re-opens it then I want the scroll position to be maintained.

I am using the Paging 3 library with a Remote Mediator so all of the data is saved locally in a Room Database.

The adapter is hosted in a fragment and I have already tried the following

```
private var state: Parcelable? = null // initiating a parclable variable


    override fun onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      adapter.stateRestorationPolicy = 
      RecyclerView.Adapter.StateRestorationPolicy.PREVENT_WHEN_EMPTY
      binding.recyclerView.layoutManager!!.onRestoreInstanceState(state)
    }

    override fun onPause() {
      super.onPause()
      state = binding.recyclerView.layoutManager!!.onSaveInstanceState()
    }
```

I am using the latest version of the recycler view library

```
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0'
```

But this does not work.

Comment: You can you SharedPreferences this.

Comment: You can save data to the Room database. Create a table for different settings (id, key, value) and save a position there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use recyclerViewId.getLayoutManager().findFirstVisibleItemPosition() to get the the first item index that showing at the screen.
save it in Bundle in onSaveInstanceState() method
when user stop the app(not kill) the position will be saved in Bundle
and when start app get position saved in the Bundle in onRestoreInstanceState() method

for example

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(icicle);

  int position = recyclerViewId.getLayoutManager().findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

  saveInstance.putInt("recyclerViewLastPosition", position);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        int position = savedInstanceState.getInt("recyclerViewLastPosition", 0);
        recyclerViewId.scrollToPosition(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this works, why the author accepted this answer? It saves position during runtime, but not after app closing and opening.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  **SharedPreferences** for this, when you are closing the app save the position in the preferences.

```
  SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("Position", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putInt("position", position);
    editor.apply();
```

After that you can get the **position** with it when you are re-opening the app.

```
 SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("Position", MODE_PRIVATE);
 int position= settings.getInt("position", null);
```

Comment: A good solution, but why do you use strings?

Comment: Its just an example you can change type according to your need.

Comment: Yes, that would be better.

Comment: @CoolMind check out my profile, maybe something will help you.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **savedInstanceState** for this by putting the last position into a bundle and on onResume method get saved position

for example:

```
onCreate(savedInstanceState:Bundle){

  savedInstanceState.put("yourKey",position)

  }
```

And when getting back

```
  onResume(savedInstanceState:Bundle){
   savedInstantState.get("yourKey")
  }
```